# Datastage defining ; as delimiter and !; as not a delimeter

Tags: delimiter, datastage

I have a data txt file which looks like following

1;2;3;4;5
1;2;3!;4;4;5

I'm expecting my output should look like as follows after reading the sequential file.

1  2  3  4  5
1  2  34  4  5

since there is only possiblity to define what's the delimiter in Datastage it don't detect !; as not a delimiter.

Could someone let me how can i overcome this problem.

Comment: So you expect two rows as result? With how many columns? One? Provide more information please

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher I'm expecting 5 columns in the first row they should be 1 2 3 4 5 and in the second row 1 2 34 4 5. Here in the second row 3rd column it should be 34. I have solved this problem by using Field, Count, Ereplace and Change functions. But, It is a bit complicated logic. So, searching for easy option.

Comment: This anomaly may just be the tip of the iceberg - or may be the only error you ever see in the data.  Have you any knowledge about the range and number of the errors in the data?  Knowing this may better inform your approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to import it as a single column and and remove the "!," in a transformer and then do a column import stage dividing up the columns.

Comment: That is what I have exactly done as explained earlier by knowing from which column is this !: is coming and split the data (Talking about 2 nd row) into two strings as 1;2 and 3!;4;5 using field function and wrote a logic as change(second string,"!;","!", count(second string,":")-3). It means, the Second string should contain only ';' and change all '!;' to '!' from the front until we see only 3 ';' in it. The result will be as expected as 34;4;5. Then join the 1 and 2 strings with concat(first string:';':second string) which gives the string 1;2;34;4;5 and in final divide the string 2 f5 cols

Comment: If you follow my solution you just got 1 column at first and you could easily remove all !. After that only numbers and ; alre left and this could be handled by the column importer

Comment: Let's say I have a data as 1;2;3!;4;5 ----> I'm expecting data of 5 columns (1,2,3!,4,5). If i follow your instructions data becomes 4 columns with NULL in the 5th column as (1,2,34,5,NULL) which I don't want to see.

Comment: Define clearly what you want - the example above shows 6 columns and would be reduced to 5 - the new example you made up in the comment before wold return 4 but you never defined what should happen in this case. It does not make sense for me to guess you needs...

Answer (score 0):

Read data as a single string. Convert "!;" to "" using Ereplace() or Change() function. Then parse using Transformer loop or Column Import stage.